# Why am I seeing loop and squashfs in "blkid" output?

Tags: 20.04, snap, squashfs, loop-device

executing `$blkid` on 20.4 I am seeing a output as below. I don't understand what loop and squashfs are here? Could someone explain? Does this have anything to do with snap installed applications?

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
```